# Can I make a ASP.Net MVC Html.ValidationMessageFor visible in javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, html-helper

I have a view that does not submit but the user clicks on an actionlink and depending on the information filled in on the page the actionlink will open another page _blank or not (I am using the link click event in javascript to validate the data before the page opens).
The client validation messages for the required data is shown as alerts via jquery/javascript at the moment, I was just wondering if a Html.ValidationMessageFor field could be displayed on the page rather than calling alerts for validation errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try firing the validator on your action link click:

```
 $("#myForm").validate();
```